# Bootstrap input group with select as add-on

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

No matter what I try, I can't get an input with a select box as an addon.

Here is what I want:

[image]

However, I can't seem to make it work by following Bootstrap guide for input groups:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
    <select class="form-control input-group-addon">
        <option>Item 1</option>
        <option>Item 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7qwb9pxj/1/)

Can someone help me out here? I've been searching for some time now!

Comment: From the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) (in bold red letters): _We do not support multiple form-controls in a single input group._  look into  [bootstrap's dropdowns as an addon](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-dropdowns).

Comment: thanks for that mate. Why don't I ever read the docs well enough?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make the change by adding custom styles to the select.

I added a class to the "input-group" called "select-group" and target the input field and select.

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-group select-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
        <select class="form-control input-group-addon">
            <option>Item 1</option>
            <option>Item 2</option>
        </select>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.select-group input.form-control{ width: 65%}
.select-group select.input-group-addon { width: 35%; }
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7qwb9pxj/2/)

Comment: is it fine to add a bootstrap select to this input-group as like you have suggested here? I would like to use the same thing so is there a mandatory reason why I should not do it like this? Not 100% sure why Bootstrap does not allow it so...

Comment: @Krystyna Yes we can add it like the above example. Also you can use [this](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-dropdowns) if that's what you need.

Comment: I am using the bootstrap select by silviomoreto. I would like to enforce bootstrap columns (col-md-2) for the input field and the select, but this doesnt work, and when I change your width % sizes, the select just wraps to the left under the input field, so it doesnt really work..

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div class="input-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="100">
       <div class="input-group-append">
         <select name="" id="" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" 
           type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
           <option class="dropdown-item" value="USD">USD</option>
           <option class="dropdown-item" value="%">%</option>
           <option class="dropdown-item" value="Coin">Coin</option>
         </select>
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).